# MySQL Seems to sort rows before if statement changes values of columns, I need to sort it after values been changed

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

This real Query

```
SELECT  IF(`AutomobilioMarke`='Vauxhall', 'Opel', `AutomobilioMarke`),
        `AutomobilioModelis`, `AutomobilioVariklis`, `kurTip`,
        `VarGal`, `GamintojoKodas`, `AutomobilioMetai`, `Kaina`,
        `ID`, `Kur`, `VArkliai`, `VariklioTuris`
    FROM  Detale AS p
    JOIN  AutomobiliuList AS r  ON r.KType = p.KTipas
    WHERE  (`AutomobilioMarke` != '')
      AND  (`KatId` = 4840  OR  `KatId` = 4844)
      AND  (`Quantity` != 0)
    ORDER BY  `AutomobilioMarke` ASC, `AutomobilioModelis` ASC,
              `GamintojoKodas` ASC, `AutomobilioMetai` ASC
```

This where i think problem is:

```
SELECT IF(`Make`='Vauxhall', "Opel", `Make`) FROM Cars ORDER BY `Make` ASC
```

I get Rows ordered like this:

- Opel   ....
- Peugeot   ....
- Renault   ....
- Rover ....
- Opel ....

I want:

- Opel ....
- Opel   ....
- Peugeot   ....
- Renault   ....
- Rover ....

It seems like it sorts out first and then changes values, is there any way to change values and then sort it out ???

Or Sort Change Sort, or just get wanted values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not alias the column returned by the expression:

```
IF(`AutomobilioMarke`='Vauxhall', 'Opel', `AutomobilioMarke`)
```

so if you think the `ORDER BY` would sort by the result of this expression then you are wrong, because it sorts by the column `AutomobilioMarke` as it is in the table.
So define an alias and also use it in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
  IF(`AutomobilioMarke`='Vauxhall', 'Opel', `AutomobilioMarke`) AS AutoMarke, 
  `AutomobilioModelis`, 
  `AutomobilioVariklis`, 
  `kurTip`, 
  `VarGal`, 
  `GamintojoKodas`, 
  `AutomobilioMetai`, 
  `Kaina`, 
  `ID`,
  `Kur`, 
  `VArkliai`, 
  `VariklioTuris` 
FROM Detale AS p JOIN AutomobiliuList AS r 
ON r.KType = p.KTipas 
WHERE(`AutomobilioMarke` != '') AND (`KatId` = 4840 OR `KatId` = 4844) AND (`Quantity` != 0)
ORDER BY AutoMarke ASC, `AutomobilioModelis` ASC, `GamintojoKodas` ASC, `AutomobilioMetai` ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, Yeah you totaly right, I overlooked that. Thanks again